# Codeigniter URI route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have various static pages and I dont want to create independent controller for them all.

Say I want to create a controller named `page` and have all of the static pages as functions.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends Frontend_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function store(){
        $this->load->view('public/store');
    }
    public function contact(){
        $this->load->view('public/contact');
    }
    public function about(){
        $this->load->view('public/about');
    }    
}
```

Is there anyway to modify the URI routes so that I wouldnt have to type `mydomain.com/page/contact` but I could type `mydomain.com/contact` to view the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `application/config/routes.php`

You can add as:

```
$route['contact'] = "page/contacts";
$route['store'] = "page/store";
...
```

Comment: @sohanmax02: cool! I love how easy stuff like this is in CI :)

Comment: @itachi I find it to be most easy in `clampuchi` - which is yet to be developed by the way..

Comment: how can that be?? I am the BDFL for that project! >:D

Answer (score 1):

In my `application/config/routes.php` I use the following regex to do that.  Most sites I work on are relatively small so I list all of the controllers in the following snippet (because it's easier than listing all of the static pages)

```
$route['^(?!controller1|controller2).*'] = "page/$1";
```

The logic basically says that *If the path does not start with controller1 or controller2 then use page as the controller* for urls like `http://domain.tld/page`

For not having to create 10+ static routes for all my static pages it keeps it pretty simple.